# O tamanho da cadeia de caracteres ultrapassa o valor definido na propriedade maxJsonLength

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Estou tentando gerar um arquivo `Json` a partir de um `SELECT` da tabela do SQL SERVER 2016. Existe cerca de 4713 linhas, isso está ultrapassa o valor definido na propriedade `maxJsonLength`. Consigo ultrapassar esse valor definido?

Web.config

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Class Model:

```
public class ProcessoMobile
        {
            public string Natureza { get; set; }
            public string Vara { get; set; }
            public string Agencia { get; set; }
            public string Comarca { get; set; }
            public Decimal Valor { get; set; }
            public string GCPJ { get; set; }
            public string ParteContraria { get; set; }
            public string AdvogadoContraria { get; set; }
            public string Telefone { get; set; }
            public DateTime DataDistribuicao { get; set; }
            public string Carteira { get; set; }
            public string Contrato { get; set; }
            public string CidadeAgencia { get; set; }
            public string ProcessoID { get; set; }
            public bool PesquisaBens { get; set; }
            public bool Ativo { get; set; }
            public bool Arquivado { get; set; }
            public bool Irrecuperavel { get; set; }
            public bool Encerrado { get; set; }
            public string CarteiraAtual { get; set; }
            public string ContratoAtual { get; set; }
            public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
            public string Conta { get; set; }
            public string NomeAdvogado { get; set; }
        }
```

Função:

```
public static void CriaJson()
{
    List<ProcessoMobile> processList = new List<ProcessoMobile>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select_Processo_Mobile", con))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProcessoMobile p = new ProcessoMobile()
                {

                    Natureza = reader["Natureza"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Natureza"]),
                    Vara = reader["Vara"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Vara"]),
                    Agencia = reader["Agencia"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Agencia"]),
                    Comarca = reader["Comarca"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Comarca"]),
                    Valor = reader["Valor"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? decimal.MinValue :
                    Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Valor"]),
                    GCPJ = reader["GCPJ"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["GCPJ"]),
                    ParteContraria = reader["ParteContraria"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["ParteContraria"]),
                    AdvogadoContraria = reader["AdvogadoContraria"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["AdvogadoContraria"]),
                    Telefone = reader["Telefone"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Telefone"]),
                    DataDistribuicao = reader["DataDistribuicao"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue :
                    Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataDistribuicao"]),
                    Carteira = reader["Carteira"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Carteira"]),
                    Contrato = reader["Contrato"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Contrato"]),
                    CidadeAgencia = reader["CidadeAgencia"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["CidadeAgencia"]),
                    ProcessoID = reader["ProcessoID"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["ProcessoID"]),
                    PesquisaBens = reader["PesquisaBens"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? false :
                    Convert.ToBoolean(reader["PesquisaBens"]),
                    Ativo = reader["Ativo"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? false :
                    Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Ativo"]),
                    Arquivado = reader["Arquivado"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? false :
                    Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Arquivado"]),
                    Irrecuperavel = reader["Irrecuperavel"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? false :
                    Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Irrecuperavel"]),
                    Encerrado = reader["Encerrado"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? false :
                    Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Encerrado"]),
                    CarteiraAtual = reader["CarteiraAtual"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["CarteiraAtual"]),
                    ContratoAtual = reader["ContratoAtual"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["ContratoAtual"]),
                    CpfCnpj = reader["CpfCnpj"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["CpfCnpj"]),
                    Conta = reader["Conta"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["Conta"]),
                    NomeAdvogado = reader["NomeAdvogado"] ==
                    DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :
                    Convert.ToString(reader["NomeAdvogado"]),

                };
                processList.Add(p);
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();

            var jsonSerialiser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(processList);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\processList.json", jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, tanto para `Serialization` quando `Deserialize` eu utilizo o  *framework Newtonsoft* do `namespace` `Newtonsoft.Json` que, na maioria das vezes, já vem incorporado ao projeto. Porém, caso não venha, é possível instala-lo pelo `Nuget`

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Enfim, vamos ao código.

Não sei o tamanho dos dados que estão vindo do seu banco de dados, mas criei uma classe equivalente a sua e atribui a todas elas o texto **"teste de SerializeObject com Newtonsoft.Json"**.

Sem grandes problemas, consegui fazer a `Serialization` de **500000** linhas.

segue como usá-lo

```
public static void CriaJson()
{
    List<ProcessoMobile> processList = new List<ProcessoMobile>();

    //Código para obter os dados

    string jsonString =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processList);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\processList.json", jsonString);
}
```